# document.getElementById is NULL error

Tags: php, javascript, templates, smarty

I have a function that listens for onkeyup event, that onkeyup checks to see if a box has a value and if not blank is supposed pull the value of an elementID which is a phone number called from another page. It takes that value and inserts it in to a snippet of html that gets sent to another elementID. the folowing code is the function and the associated code.

```
<script language="javascript">
function monthlycheck() {

    var mnthchk = document.getElementById("mdamountBox");
    var cancelPhone = document.getElementById("cancelphoneLabel");
    document.getElementById("cancelphonelistLabel").value = cancelPhone; <--gives the is null error

    if(mnthchk.value!=""){

        var newHTML = "<span style='color:#24D330'> Your Monthly pledge in the amount of $__ is valid and will be deducted this time every month<br> untill you notify us of its cancellation by calling <label id='cancelphonelistLabel'>&nbsp;</label>";
        " </span>";

        document.getElementById("mnthlychkdiscoLabel").innerHTML = newHTML;
    }
}

</script>

<label id="mnthlychkdiscoLabel">&nbsp;</label> <---this is where the final data is to be displayed
<label id="cancelphoneLabel">1-800-555-1111</label> <--- this is the phone number pulled from another page,
```

all the data is pulled together in a single page when loaded but is written in separate page using smarty templates. I keep getting the entitled error and have tried a number of different things to fix it but im stumped any help is greatly appreciated.

here is a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rn5HH/

Comment: Another page? Can you access elements from another page ???

Comment: Can you throw in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to access that id before it's created.
Also `.value` is only for inputs. It looks like you are creating a label, so you'd use innerHTML instead.

Something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
function monthlycheck() {

  var mnthchk = document.getElementById("mdamountBox");
  var cancelPhone = document.getElementById("cancelphoneLabel");

  if(mnthchk.value!=""){

    var newHTML = "<span style='color:#24D330'> Your Monthly pledge in the amount of $__ is valid and will be deducted this time every month<br> untill you notify us of its cancellation by calling <label id='cancelphonelistLabel'>&nbsp;</label></span>";

    document.getElementById("mnthlychkdiscoLabel").innerHTML = newHTML;

    document.getElementById("cancelphonelistLabel").innerHTML = cancelPhone; //<--gives the is null error

  }
}
</script>

<label id="mnthlychkdiscoLabel">&nbsp;</label> <---this is where the final data is to be displayed

<label id="cancelphoneLabel">1-800-555-1111</label> <--- this is the phone number pulled from another page,
```

I'm not 100% what you are trying to do, so i just tried to make it work. There are many things you could probably simplify in this. It would help if you could create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show it more clearly.

**Edit:**

Fixed the fiddle so it works and shows the phone number: 
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rn5HH/1/)

Is that what it's supposed to do?

Comment: The value property is not just for inputs. Most form controls may have a value attribute (and all may have a value property), as well as some other elements like LI and PARAM.